# Inherited member from an abstract class can't be initialized by the inherited constructor

Tags: c++, visual-c++, constructor, abstract-class

```
class CarPart
{
public:
    CarPart(): name(""), price(0) {}
    virtual int getPrice() = 0;//{return price;}
protected:
    int price;
    string name;
};

class Tire: public CarPart
{
public:
    virtual int getPrice() {return price;}
    Tire(): CarPart(), name("Tire"), price(50)
    {}
};
```

Visual 2010 tells me name and price are not members of deriv, but they are inherited (error c2614).
What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: point of design, `protected` attributes are bad from an encapsulation point of view. You'd be better off having them `private` and provide accessors (not necessarily virtual). `private` also mean that you can change the exact implementation without worrying about changing all of the `Derived` classes.

Comment: @ Matthieu M: Better off making them private and **not** providing accessors or make the class a property bag and let everything be public/protected. A class is supposed to hold state and allow **Actions** on the object that manipulate state, you are not supposed to expose the state directly for manipulation. Accessors expose state and impose a binding on implementation (you may be reducing the binding surface using accessors over members but there is still a binding that will make changing the implementation hard).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You cannot initialize members that is not an immediate member of your class. `n` is not an immediate member of `deriv`, it's an immediate member of `base`.

However, `n` is accessible to `deriv`, so you can always assign it in your `deriv` constructor, but you should really initialize it in the `base` constructor.

<strike>Also, you can't have `virtual` constructors. Did you mean to use `virtual` destructors?</strike>

```
class base
{
public:
    base() : n(0) {} // Are you sure you don't want this?
    virtual void show() = 0;
protected:
    int n;
};

class deriv : public base
{
public:
    deriv() 
    {
        n = 0;
    }

    virtual void show() {}
};
```

**EDIT (A response to the OP's edit):** You don't need virtual methods for this:

```
class CarPart
{
public:
    CarPart(const char* newName, int newPrice) : name(newName), price(newPrice) {}

    const std::string& GetName() const { return name; }
    int GetPrice() const               { return price; }
private:
    std::string name;
    int price;
};

class Tire : public CarPart
{
public:
    Tire() : CarPart("Tire", 50) {}
};
```

Assuming that all your `CarPart`s has to have a name and a price, this should be more than sufficient.

Comment: It's a member of base, so if deriv inherits from base, it's also another member of deriv since it is protected, inherited publicly.

Comment: @gokoon: Well, what I meant that it has to be an "immediate" member of the class. Think about it this way from a memory management perspective: The `base` class is responsible for initializing the `n` data member because `base` "owns" `n`. Yes, `deriv` can access the `n` data member, but `deriv` is not responsible for initializing/uninitializing it.

Comment: mixing high level and low level programming, brilliant.

Comment: @In silico: regarding the "you don't need virtual methods from this", you probably don't want virtual methods to be called from constructors/destructors.

Answer (score 2):

1) n is left uninitialized in base;

2) `virtual deriv(): n(0) {}` is not a constructor

You probably wanted:

```
class base
{
public:
   base(int n) : n(n) {}

...

class deriv: public base
{
public:
deriv(): base(0) {}
...
```

Comment: I don't want to have a constructor with a parameter.

Answer (score 1):

Note, constructors can't be virtual!

You can't initialize members of a base class using the member initialization syntax. Either initialize `n` in the base class (which is the correct way to do it):

```
class base 
{ 
public: 
    base(int n_ = 0) : n(n_) {}
    virtual void show() = 0;  
protected: 
    int n; 
}; 

class deriv: public base 
{ 
public: 
    deriv() : base(0) {} 
    void show() {} 
};
```

or assign a value to `n` inside the constructor of the derived class (not good, at least not without initialization in the base class:

```
class base 
{ 
public: 
    base(int n_ = 0) : n(n_) {}
    virtual void show() = 0;  
protected: 
    int n; 
}; 

class deriv: public base 
{ 
public: 
    deriv() { n = 1; } 
    void show() {} 
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't initialize a base class member in a derived class, since the base class is already constructed before the derived class is initialized. You could provide a constructor that accepts a parameter for the value of `n`:

```
base(int val) : n(val) {}
```

Then delegate to it in your `deriv` constructor:

```
deriv() : base(0) {}
```